# Why does my C++ extended stored procedure not write to the console?

Tags: c++, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write simple extended stored procedure using C++ dll for writing some text to console. I have made it in next way:

1. created a dll using c++ (look at .cpp and .h files below)
2. tested this dll from win32 console app (all worked as tic tak toe)
3. move got dll file into sql server bin directory
4. executed `sp_addextendedproc 'xp_test','xp_test.dll'` from management studio
5. executed extended proc(`exec xp_test`)

When I have executed the last step there is a prompt appeared that notify me that query is executed saccesfully but there is no any console window with expected hello world prompt. Where is my fault?

```
//test.h file
#ifdef MYLIBAPI
#else
#define MYLIBAPI extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#include <srv.h>
MYLIBAPI SRVRETCODE xp_test(SRV_PROC *srvproc);
```

```
// xp_test.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#define MYLIBAPI extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

SRVRETCODE xp_test(SRV_PROC *srvproc){
    cout << "Hello world" << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I also have tried to use Console API but this also do not allow to write to console

```
SRVRETCODE xp_test(SRV_PROC *srvproc){
    AllocConsole();
    HANDLE out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD writtenCount;
    LPCTSTR msg = L"Hello world\n";
    WriteConsole(out, msg, lstrlen(msg), &writtenCount, NULL);
    Sleep(5000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? It could be a dependency issue, make sure all is statically linked into your program.

Comment: @demorge VS 2010 ultimate edition

Comment: Try this: Project Property Pages -> Config Prop -> C/C++ -> Code generation -> Runtime library -> now choose the ones w/o DLL for debug and release.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't know anything about C++, there is no console because SQL Server is usually running as a service without an interactive session or desktop, so it isn't clear where you expect the output to go.

As the documentation [explains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164743%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), an extended stored procedure returns result sets to the server using the [Extended Stored Procedure API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164692.aspx), but your code doesn't seem to do this.

Fortunately, Microsoft actually provides a [Hello World example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa197372%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) of their own; have you reviewed it?

And finally, please note the [warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164716.aspx) in MSDN that extended stored procedures are now deprecated, will be removed from SQL Server and should not be used for new development.

Comment: ok, I think I've figured out your point of view but in that way Console API would resolve the issue, but no. I know that extended procs now are deprecated but I really need to use it